# Is there any way to debug SharePoint online Remote Event Receiver i.e. provider hosted app without using Azure Service Bus?

Tags: azure, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Is there any way to debug SharePoint online Remote Event Receiver i.e. provider hosted app without using Azure Service Bus ? I don't have Azure Service bus subscription as my organization doesn't allow to connect code over there.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's a provider hosted app...you can debug it like any other web app.  For example, I have typically deployed my provider hosted apps to Azure, and then use Visual Studio to debug the Azure web site.  I've used it in the past on remote event receivers as well.

It's rather lengthy, but you can look at aspects of such a design here: https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/02/28/cloudtopia-connecting-o365-apps-azure-and-cortana-part-1/.

You have to enable debugging on the web site - have you tried that?  I described a second way to do it here if you want to give it a shot: https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/02/27/another-cool-way-to-remotely-debug-azure-web-sites/.

Comment: I tried the same but when I am trying to debug it via Visual studio, I am getting a popup that Azure Service bus is not enabled.

Comment: I edited my answer below, you might see if the second link I provided enables you to do connect to it.  I've done it many times and never used Azure Service bus.